# How to only print 5 node of a tree using a recursive function

Tags: c, printing, recursion, tree

So Basically I want to only print the first 5 node of a AVL tree using recursion

```
    void printInOrder(void* theTree, void(*printnode)(void *data)) {

        struct AVLTreeNode *node= (struct AVLTreeNode*)theTree;

        if (node == NULL) return;

         printInOrder(node->left, printnode);

        (printnode)(node->data);

        printInOrder(node->right, printnode);

     }
```

the code above is a recursive inorder print i would just like to modify it to only print out the first 5 nodes of the tree. Also here is the printnode function

```
    void printnode(void *node){

        struct todo *printnode = node;

        printf("%s, %d\n", printnode->activity, printnode->priority);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell the function when to stop: you can supply a counter of how many nodes are still available to print (initially 5), and each time one node is actually printed, you decrement the counter.

(Or you can *increment* the counter, but in that case the check has two terms - current counter value and maximum counter value - and you need to pass both as parameters, or make them global variables).

If you need to do something in addition to print, or need a more flexible

```
int printInOrder(void* theTree, int remaining, void(*printnode)(void *data))
{
    if (0 == remaining)
        return 0;
    struct AVLTreeNode *node= (struct AVLTreeNode*)theTree;
    if (node == NULL) return remaining;
    remaining = printInOrder(node->left, remaining, printnode);

    // When actually printing nodes, decrement counter
    (printnode)(node->data); remaining--;

    return printInOrder(node->right, remaining, printnode);
}

printInOrder(tree, 5, ...);
```

If you need to do something in addition to print, or need a more flexible function, you can do the same but passing the parameters to `printnode`:

```
void printInOrder(void* theTree, int remaining, int(*printnode)(int r, void *data))
{
    struct AVLTreeNode *node= (struct AVLTreeNode*)theTree;
    if (node == NULL) return remaining;
    printInOrder(node->left, remaining, printnode);
    remaining = (printnode)(remaining, node->data);
    printInOrder(node->right, remaining, printnode);
}
```

In this second case, it is `printnode` that manipulates the counter, while `printInOrder` just passes it along. Now, `printnode` gets called once for each node, but does the actual printing only when counter is nonzero, and can do any other housekeeping in all cases.

Comment: Why return zero if `node == NULL`?

Comment: Well spotted. No reason, except not having thought it out.